# Yii2 Basic template - How to login from mysql database

Tags: php, yii, authentication, yii2

I tried to implement the User Model and LoginForm Model in Yii basic template to validate user logins. I created a database and connected to it. The database as a table user and fields called username, password, authKey, and acessToken populated with values. Extended the User Model from ActiveRecord and implemented \yii\web\IdentityInterface in order to make the in-built Yii2 functions do their job. Also written this method:

```
public static function tableName() { return 'user'; }
```

Every time I try to login it throws -> username or password incorrect, from the `validatepassword()` in LoginForm Model.

**Here is my code:**

LoginForm Model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

/**
 * LoginForm is the model behind the login form.
 */
class LoginForm extends Model
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = true;

    private $_user = false;

    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // username and password are both required
            [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
            // rememberMe must be a boolean value
            ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
            // password is validated by validatePassword()
            ['password', 'validatePassword'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Validates the password.
     * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
     *
     * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
     * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
     */
    public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
    {
        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();

            if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
     * @return boolean whether the user is logged in successfully
     */
    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by [[username]]
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === false) {
            $this->_user = User::findByUsername($this->username);
        }

        return $this->_user;
    }
}
```

…and here is my User.php Model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class User extends ActiveRecord implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface
{
    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $authKey;
    public $accessToken;

    public static function tableName() { return 'user'; }

       /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id) {
        $user = self::find()
                ->where([
                    "id" => $id
                ])
                ->one();
        if (!count($user)) {
            return null;
        }
        return new static($user);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $userType = null) {

        $user = self::find()
                ->where(["accessToken" => $token])
                ->one();
        if (!count($user)) {
            return null;
        }
        return new static($user);
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by username
     *
     * @param  string      $username
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByUsername($username) {
        $user = self::find()
                ->where([
                    "username" => $username
                ])
                ->one();
        if (!count($user)) {
            return null;
        }
        return new static($user);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAuthKey() {
        return $this->authKey;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey) {
        return $this->authKey === $authKey;
    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param  string  $password password to validate
     * @return boolean if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password) {
        return $this->password === $password;
    }

}
```

I don't know what else should i do, perhaps it has a problem in validating the password or find the username, in Yii2 debug it shows that is proper connected to the mysql database.

Don't messed with the siteController `actionLogin()` because it is equal to the advanced template and i think it correct to stay that way.

In short, the below function keeps throwing "Incorrect username or password.":

```
public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
{
    if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
        $user = $this->getUser();

        if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
            $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
        }
    }
}
```

I don't want to give up, but I'm considering go back to the old Yii1.xx. There I could easily query the database and make a good login system working.

I spent almost 72 hours with this login problem and no solution solved it for the basic Yii2 template.

I don't want to use static `$users` that came as default in the package.

**EDIT 2**
**siteController.php**

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use app\models\LoginForm;
use app\models\ContactForm;
use yii\helpers\url;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['logout'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }

    public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->redirect(Url::toRoute(['contacto/index'])); 
        } else {
            return $this->render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function actionLogout()
    {
        Yii::$app->user->logout();

        return $this->goHome();
    }

    public function actionContact()
    {
        $model = new ContactForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->contact(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('contactFormSubmitted');

            return $this->refresh();
        } else {

                return $this->redirect(Url::toRoute(['contacto/create2']));
        }
    }

    public function actionAbout()
    {
        return $this->render('about');
    }

    public function actionSkills()
    {
        return $this->render('skills');
    }

    public function actionPortfolio()
    {
        return $this->render('portfolio');
    }

    // tradução do site
    public function beforeAction($action) {
        if (Yii::$app->session->has('lang')) {
            Yii::$app->language = Yii::$app->session->get('lang');
        } else {
            Yii::$app->language = 'us';
        }
        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }

    public function actionLangus(){  
        Yii::$app->session->set('lang', 'us'); //or $_GET['lang']
        return $this->redirect(Url::toRoute(['site/index']));   
    }

    public function actionLangpt(){  
        Yii::$app->session->set('lang', 'pt'); //or $_GET['lang']
        return $this->redirect(Url::toRoute(['site/index']));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your controller and view as well?

Comment: HI BRETT, thank's for trying to help. I've posted the siteController. The login view is as came in original file and stackoverflow gives error when trying to paste it.

Comment: I had a look your code again, I don't use active record but it appears you are comparing the user submitted password to the hashed password that comes from the database?

Comment: Humm!! And where did you see that comparison? It is important to me to understand how things work. Thanks.

Comment: Well in your rules method you make a call to `validatePassword` which then calls `validatePassword` from your user model and passes it the password as the user entered it; and then you do a comparison in there between that password and what I believe is the password taken from the users table - you would like need to use the `validatePassword` method: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-security.html#validatePassword%28%29-detail

Comment: you would like need to use the validatePassword ?? I apologize, but i'm confused. What do i have to do ? I thought that comparing the password written in the form with password from the filed password in the table user was the right way. At least that is what i was doing in Yii1.xx and it always worked.

Comment: What are you doing when you insert the users password in the database when they register? Are you hashing it with `generatePasswordHash`?

Comment: No. For now i don't have a Gii model class to register passwords in the database. I created the database and then inserted in phpmyadmin the field values myself. But yesterday i tried with a Gii model class, extended from ActiveRecord and result was the same. :((

Comment: have u tried debugging by logging the values of the passwords u are comparing?

Comment: No. Because i don't know how to do it. But i could learn. In my code did you notice something wrong ? I ask because i followed other tutorials by the line, and it seams everything is correct.

Comment: Well in debug it says an error: 11 19:12:20.625 error yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource::loadMessages The message file for category 'yii' does not exist: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/login/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/messages/us/yii.php
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/login/controllers/SiteController.php (63)

Comment: It is in siteController on actionLogin(). But i don't know the meaning of this error.
Also the query is this:
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='acastro'

Comment: Humm!! Debug mark as red this one in siteController, actionLOgin():
return $this->redirect(Url::toRoute(['contacto/index']));

Comment: Hmmmmm..... not 100% sure on that sorry. I'm reasonably new to Yii myself. But for logging you can use: `Yii::info('message', __METHOD__)`. More info here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-logging.html

Comment: Good luck...... I have to go for now.

Comment: Hey @AndréCastro, where can i find user.php in my yii2-app-basic application. I'm also facing same problem.

Comment: Hi. You can find User.php in models folder.

Comment: The advanced app does this for you already... You could have easily ported over how the advanced app handles this into the basic app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Stop creating duplicate questions
2) remove the public declarations of variables bellow.

```
class User extends ActiveRecord implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface
{
public $id;
public $username;
public $password;
public $authKey;
public $accessToken;
```

$user->password will be empty because of this. Instead of using a magic method to get the values you are actually declaring them... they will always be empty when you use them.

Comment: SOLVED. Many thanks to Mihai P., and apologies for the duplicate.

Comment: you mean to remove replace public with protected.?

Comment: No I mean just do not declare them. If you declare variables here like this then Yii considers that they are not table fields.